# Zipkin Slueth generate different traces for same different thread(in Same request)

Tags: zipkin, spring-cloud-sleuth

I am using Zipkin Slueth with Spring boot.

Now my zipkin is working fine in normal case but when I spawn 3 new threads from main thread, it generate different traces and not 1 trace.

So i am unable to see the complete request.
Same starts working if I do everything in main thread?

My Pom for including dpendencies

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-zipkin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Properties**

```
spring.zipkin.baseUrl: http://172.16.3.197:9411/
spring.slueth.enabled: true
spring.sleuth.sampler.percentage: 1
```

My spring cloud version is Dalton.SR5

So slueth sends traces to zipkin auto. This is all I have configured for zipkin.

Can i use rxjava schedules hook? How? I am unable to use it?

Comment: You've provided almost no information. Can you read this and follow these guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: I have updated the question, can you please check it now

Answer (score 0):

You're using an ancient version of Spring CLoud. Please upgrade to latest Edgware. The RxJava support is very basic so we suggest that you use Project Reactor. To do that just migrate to Finchley and it should work out of the box with WebFlux.

Comment: I was using Edgware, but then sleuth was able to send traces to zipkin. As soon as i changed it ti Dalton, sleuth was able to ship logs to zipkin

Comment: I am more than certain that the problem lays with your code cause Spring Cloud Sleuth works fine with Zipkin in the Edgware release train.

Comment: Can you share how can i use rxjavascheduleshook?